# How to run a bash script every hour and how to kill it on cloud desktop?

Tags: bash, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I want to run a bash script every hour in my cloud desktop which can be done by following commands:

`while true; do ./parseScript.sh; sleep 3600; done`

```
minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute
```

But the problem is my cloud window will expire so I won't be able to kill it in future? Can anyone guide me on this, How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On every modern linux distribution you have the [`cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) utility. This tool allow you to schedule tasks regularly (or not).

To schedule your task, you have to launch `crontab`and then, inside the file presented (which is the list of your scheduled tasks), put something like this :

```
0 * * * * /absolute/path/to/your/parseScript.sh
```

This will launch every hour at `0` minute (so, at 0:00, 1:00, 2:00....) your script (give the absolute path of your script)

With very last versions of cron, you can even use something easier :

```
@hourly /absolute/path/to/your/parseScript.sh
```

Because new shortcuts have been implemented (@hourly, @daily, @weekly, @monthly...)

Comment: yeah this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

this solution:

```
$watch --interval=3600 command
```

No sudoer user, no config, ideal for just use from time to time as a dirty solution.

Also, you can cancel that execution whenever you want

Comment: 'watch' is good to refresh the display at a specific interval. Not to execute a command. If you switch tab on your terminal, then switch back to the 'watch' tab, it executes again whatever the interval